# Deploy react app on nginx running on windows?

Tags: nginx, create-react-app, nginx-config

there isn't a lot of discussions about serving react app on nginx running on Windows.

I have a create-react-app I'd like to deploy to my own windows machine that runs an nginx server.
The app is previously running on Vercel and I'd like to move it to my own home server.

I followed instructions I could find online and did the following.

1. `npm run build` to get the `build` folder
2. configured my nginx.conf as follows

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  root "C:/Deployments/App/build";
  index index.html;
  location / {
     try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

3. `nginx -s reload` to reload my nginx server

I did the above, but when I try to access `localhost`, i get the default nginx page.

Then I tried replacing the port in the above `.conf` file from `80` to `8080`, re-did step 3, then it gives me a blank page.

When I inspected that page, it is the `"You need to enable javascript to run this page"` page.

I'm suspecting maybe the `path` im passing in the `nginx.conf` file is incorrect? I'm confused about whether to use forward or backward slash in that file. Does anyone have encountered similar issue? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks